# Making every window transparent with xmonad

Tags: haskell, configuration, transparency, x11, xmonad

I'd like every window to be transparent, I'm using xmonad and X11. I am not very familiar with any of Haskell, xmonad or X11.

How can I configure xmonad for that? I don't even know how to even get started.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do that, you need an event hook that sets the opacity property on creation of new windows. This is what I'm using (requires `xprop` to be on the path):

```
import XMonad
import Graphics.X11.Xlib
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Word

setTransparentHook :: Event -> X All
setTransparentHook ConfigureEvent{ev_event_type = createNotify, ev_window = id} = do
  setOpacity id opacity
  return (All True) where
    opacityFloat = 0.9
    opacity = floor $ fromIntegral (maxBound :: Word32) * opacityFloat
    setOpacity id op = spawn $ "xprop -id " ++ show id ++ " -f _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY " ++ show op
setTransparentHook _ = return (All True)

main = xmonad $ def
  { handleEventHook = setTransparentHook <+> handleEventHook def }
```

#### Process

> Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.

In the spirit of this quote I'm describing my process of coming up with this. Note that I have very limited experience with all of Haskell, xmonad and X11.

The initial mindset was that I needed a script that sets the opacity on all windows (which turned out not to be exactly what I needed). I know that composite managers on linux do this kind of stuff (visual effects), so I check out the man page of compton (which I'm using) via `man compton`.

Searching for "opacity", I see the `--opacity-rule` flag, which mentions that `compton-trans` is recommended for this instead, so I look at [its source](https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/316eac0613bf342ff91cc645a6c3c80e6b9083fb/bin/compton-trans#L9-L25). Trying out the script in the command line to discover that I need the window ID to set its opacity, so I look up how to do that.

A solution was to use `xwininfo`. You can list all the windows using `xwininfo -tree -root`. I thought I needed to parse the output of that and was already looking up `awk` tutorials.

Then I get the idea: "Wait, what if I just set the opacity on window creation? Xmonad is a window manager, it should definitely have the window ID!". So I look through [xmonad's config options](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-Core.html) where I find the `handleEventHook` property. By clicking on the types `Event` and `All` I find out which imports I need (`Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras` and `Data.Monoid`).

Creating a skeleton for my event hook by coping the [default](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/10b843ad21614994b7e12fafaf300f4267aa9e40/src/XMonad/Config.hs#L118-L119):

```
import XMonad
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras
import Data.Monoid

myEventHook :: Event -> X All
myEventHook _ = return (All True)
```

Now some Haskell knowledge is needed, I want to do something when `Event` is a window creation event. Looking through the [`Event` docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11-1.8/docs/Graphics-X11-Xlib-Extras.html#t:Event) and a bit of probing, I found out I need the `ConfigureEvent` where `ev_event_type` is `createNotify` while `ev_window` is the created window ID. To use `createNotify` I also import `Graphics.X11.Xlib`:

```
import XMonad
import Graphics.X11.Xlib
import Graphics.X11.Xlib.Extras
import Data.Monoid

myEventHook :: Event -> X All
myEventHook ConfigureEvent{ ev_event_type = createNotify, ev_window = id } = do
  return (All True)
myEventHook _ = return (All True)
```

Now what do we actually want to do? We want to spawn a shell process with the `compton-trans` command. There is the simple function `spawn` used throughout xmonad:

```
myEventHook :: Event -> X All
myEventHook ConfigureEvent{ ev_event_type = createNotify, ev_window = id } = do
  spawn $ "compton-trans -w " ++ show id ++ " 50"
  return (All True)
myEventHook _ = return (All True)
```

It worked! That's great but I noticed it being a bit slow and it still has the compton dependency which isn't really needed. So I look at the `compton-trans` source again, and see [the last line that actually does the work](https://github.com/chjj/compton/blob/316eac0613bf342ff91cc645a6c3c80e6b9083fb/bin/compton-trans#L207-L208) which just uses `xprop`! Now this is great because I don't need all the stuff of `compton-trans` which does some checks and is optimized for user convenience. Using some number conversion I came up with the final version as shown above. It may even be faster to use the direct path to the executable.

I sometimes also used the `ghci ~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` to check some types and `man xprop`/`man whatever` to check the documentation.

I hope this helps fellow xmonads to getting started! If someone has some improvements, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, i met `Not in scope: type constructor or class Word32'`, where goes wrong?

Comment: @陳力 Sounds like you need `import Data.Word`

Comment: Is there any way of only setting that opacity based on the application name? e.g. I would like to exclude Firefox from the windows which have their opacity changed